# How to get the "NS" record(s) of a given domain name by using C#?

Tags: c#, dns

I have a big problem with the NameServer(s) of a given DomainName. Actually what i want to do is a simple transaction but after searching alot code snippets on the internet and also libraries on nuget package manager I couldn't find a solution.

I have domain name like "www.example.com" and i want to get its Domain server(s) by using C# code.

There are some libraries on nuget but those are all using 'whois' search mechanism but i can't trust them all. Because they return back strings like any of those whois search results on web pages and every string result can be a different one because of using different whois search web sites behind the scenes.

Some network experts says i should use something like "nslookup" command on powershell by using C# to retrieve trustable results.

Comment: `nslookup` seems like a reasonable suggestion. Did you try? What _have_ you tried? What happened? How was that different from what you wanted?

Comment: @PeterDuniho i'm not a network guy and i dont use powershell codes alot on my daily life. However i gave a shoot for powershell on console ui to see what happens for some domain names. After using nslookup command retrived me exactly the cottect results!! After seeing this i wanted to ask a question here in the community to do this by C# code.

Comment: Given that you've confirmed `nslookup` does what you want, and given that it's easily invoked either via the `Process` class (i.e. via the regular command line) or through PowerShell, that's the way I'd go. That way you avoid having to include a third-party library with your distribution. But if you can't stand that idea, it seems you have an answer that works using a third-party library, as an alternative to using the built-in Windows features.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I generally dislike using external processes (and parsing the result out) since the output from these *could* (not that it *should*) change in future versions (while, using a library, as long as you maintain the version, are sure to have consistent results). This is usually less of a problem in unix (where piping and parsing is the norm), but has been a problem with Windows. Specially with non-english versions (localizations get updates that sometimes break the result).

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz just as an extra comment, although it's technically correct, what you want to do is not what is *usually* called a "dns lookup" (that generally gets the "A" record). You are trying to "find the authoritative nameserver records of a DNS entry". The question title might be a bit misleading for future readers.

Comment: @PeterDuniho dear peter the problem with question title that i created is just because of thinking with a programmer mind not a network guy..:) I appreciated for your detailed infos and thanks for your notify on question title, sure i will change the title to make it sense for other programmers' furure use..:)

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz actually you want the NS record, not the "A" record. I'll edit :-)

Comment: @PeterDuniho ohh man, the community will get my rights to ask questions by baning me just at the begining of my learning..:/ okay dear brother, i appreciate..:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [ARSoft.Tools.Net](http://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/), theoretically (I haven't really tried), you should be able to request the NS records of a domain.

Something like:

```
var resp = DnsClient.Default.Resolve("mydomain.com", RecordType.Ns);
var nsrecords = resp.AnswerRecords.OfType<NsRecord>();
foreach (var record in nsrecords) {
    Console.WriteLine(record.NameServer);
}
```

Note that this would return the nameserver **hosts**, but those should be easily translated to an IP by using `Dns.GetHostAddresses` (or the same `ARSoft.Tools.Net` library)

This is totally untested, but should be what you are looking after if I understood the question right.

#### Update

I actually made a test program and works just fine. Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns;

namespace SOTestDNS
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var resp = DnsClient.Default.Resolve("google.com", RecordType.Ns);
      var nsrecords = resp.AnswerRecords.OfType<NsRecord>();
      foreach (var record in nsrecords)
      {
        Console.Write(record.NameServer);
        foreach (var address in Dns.GetHostAddresses(record.NameServer))
        {
          Console.WriteLine(" -> " + address);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
ns1.google.com -> 216.239.32.10
ns3.google.com -> 216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com -> 216.239.38.10
ns2.google.com -> 216.239.34.10
```

### Disclaimer

I'm not affiliated in **absolutely any way** to the library I used. Just found that it was the right easiest tool for the job since you mentioned that using a third party library was ok.

Comment: It just works fine. A big thank for your answer..:)